# Run-time error '1004' in a If else statement program

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use two cells to determine which value to return back. The goal is to read in cell Z3 to determine which height to use, then cell AA3 to determine which Class to use based off the value the height provided. Once the class is found i would like it to print to cell AB3 then repeat for the next row and so on.

I am currently getting a Run Time error 1004. I am not sure what is causing this I looked it up and said it could be cause by an empty variable but I am not seeing it. Any help would be great thanks!

This is for a small project at work I am not great at VBA and just wanted to try and make a task easier and not take as long.

```
     Private Sub CRIC_CLASS_Click()
         Dim POLES As Worksheet
         Dim cell_value As String     ' Length
         Dim cell_value2 As String    ' MPCRIC
         Dim i As Integer             ' first intger for for loop
         Dim Class As String          ' Stores class value to return
         Dim Row As Integer   
         Set POLES = ActiveSheet
             For i = 3 To 500
             cell_value = POLES.Cells(i, "Z").Value
             cell_value2 = POLES.Cells(i, "AA").Value                       
                 If cell_value = 50 Then            
                     Row = 7                
                 ElseIf cell_value = 55 Then            
                     Row = 8            
                 ElseIf cell_value = 60 Then            
                     Row = 9            
                 ElseIf cell_value = 65 Then            
                     Row = 10            
                 ElseIf cell_value = 70 Then            
                     Row = 11            
                 ElseIf cell_value = 75 Then            
                     Row = 12            
                 ElseIf cell_value = 80 Then            
                     Row = 13            
                 ElseIf cell_value = 85 Then            
                     Row = 14            
                 ElseIf cell_value = 90 Then            
                     Row = 15            
                 ElseIf cell_value = 95 Then             
                     Row = 16            
                 ElseIf cell_value = 100 Then            
                     Row = 17            
                 End If            
' Check for height is 50            
            If Row = 7 And cell_value2 <= 34 Then
                Class = 4
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 36.5 Then
                Class = 3
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 39.3 Then
                Class = 2
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 42.1 Then
                Class = 1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 44.6 Then
                Class = H1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 47.4 Then
                Class = H2
            Else: Class = NA
            End If            
' Check for height is 55            
            If Row = 8 And cell_value2 <= 35.4 Then
                Class = 4
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 37.8 Then
                Class = 3
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 40.7 Then
                Class = 2
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 43.5 Then
                Class = 1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 46.4 Then
                Class = H1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 48.8 Then
                Class = H2
            Else: Class = NA
            End If            
' Check for height is 60            
            If Row = 9 And cell_value2 <= 36.3 Then
                Class = 4
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 39.2 Then
                Class = 3
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 42 Then
                Class = 2
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 44.9 Then
                Class = 1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 47.7 Then
                Class = H1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 50.6 Then
                Class = H2
            Else: Class = NA
            End If                        
 ' Check for height is 65            
            If Row = 10 And cell_value2 <= 37.7 Then
                Class = 4
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 40.5 Then
                Class = 3
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 43.4 Then
                Class = 2
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 46.3 Then
                Class = 1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 49.1 Then
                Class = H1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 52 Then
                Class = H2
            Else: Class = NA
            End If                       
' Check for height is 70            
            If Row = 11 And cell_value2 <= 38.6 Then
                Class = 4
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 41.9 Then
                Class = 3
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 44.8 Then
                Class = 2
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 47.6 Then
                Class = 1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 50.5 Then
                Class = H1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 53.3 Then
                Class = H2
            Else: Class = NA
            End If            
' Check for height is 75            
            If Row = 12 And cell_value2 <= 42.8 Then
                Class = 3
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 45.7 Then
                Class = 2
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 49 Then
                Class = 1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 51.9 Then
                Class = H1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 55.1 Then
                Class = H2
            Else: Class = NA
            End If            
 ' Check for height is 80            
            If Row = 13 And cell_value2 <= 43.7568 Then
                Class = 3
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 47.1 Then
                Class = 2
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 50.4 Then
                Class = 1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 53.2 Then
                Class = H1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 56.1 Then
                Class = H2
            Else: Class = NA
            End If            
 ' Check for height is 85            
            If Row = 14 & cell_value2 <= 44.6772 Then
                Class = 3
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 47.9778 Then
                Class = 2
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 51.2785 Then
                Class = 1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 54.5791 Then
                Class = H1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 57.4462 Then
                Class = H2
            Else: Class = NA
            End If            
 ' Check for height is 90            
            If Row = 15 And cell_value2 <= 45.5952 Then
                Class = 3
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 49.3333 Then
                Class = 2
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 52.2024 Then
                Class = 1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 55.506 Then
                Class = H1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 58.8095 Then
                Class = H2
            Else: Class = NA
            End If            
  ' Check for height is 95            
            If Row = 16 And cell_value2 <= 50.4157 Then
                Class = 2
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 53.2921 Then
                Class = 1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 57.0449 Then
                Class = H1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 60.3596 Then
                Class = H2
            Else: Class = NA
            End If            
   ' Check for height is 100            
            If Row = 16 And cell_value2 <= 51.4894 Then
                Class = 2
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 54.8138 Then
                Class = 1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 58.1383 Then
                Class = H1
            ElseIf cell_value2 <= 61.4628 Then
                Class = H2
            Else: Class = NA
            End If            
        Cells(i, "AB").Value = Class

        Next i

     End Sub
```

Comment: What is `AB` in `Cells(AB, i).Value = Class`? Also - strings normally are enclosed in quotes.

Comment: if class is a string then every time you try and assign it a value that value needs to be a string. ```Class = NA``` is trying to assign ```Class``` to the value of the variable ```NA``` which is nothing.

Comment: ^ Add `Option Explicit` to the very top of the module and declare all variables.

Comment: Think your problem has been nailed but for future reference you should tell us which line errors, especially when posting so much code.

Comment: `&` is not a logical operand in VBA. Use `And`

Comment: @Bigben the AB is what cell i was trying to send the value too. so it would be for example Cell AB3.

Comment: Cells() is `Row,Column` so `Cells(I,"AB").Value`

Comment: @Warcupine for Class = NA , I was trying to assign NA to class to print out if there was an no value read in to compare too.

Comment: Also just I had no line to reference as to what was causing the error or else I would have provided the Line with the code. I apologize for not specifying that but I do appreciate the help!

Comment: If you want ```class``` to have the value ```"NA"``` then you need to wrap it in quotes, It thinks it is a variable currently. So ```Class =  "NA"``` will get you "NA" otherwise you get a null value. The same for every value assignment of ```Class``` you have that isn't a number.

Comment: I updated the & to And and the Cells statement at the end. I am now getting a Run-time error "13". I believe this is happening after the Cells(i,"AB").Value=Class line. When i step through the code it takes me to another block of code that I didn't program and get stuck in it.

Comment: Thank you Warcupine I will make those updates

Comment: Stylistically speaking, you should look into `Select Case`. It will considerately reduce the amount of text required for this program and ensure a variable isn't accidentally swapped for another in any of those `If ElseIf` chains.